# Передвинуть обьект в край экрана

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делал игру на юнити для андроид, но при разном разрешении экрана стены то не видно, то они слишком большие. Как скриптом узнать где находиться край экрана и передвинуть туда стену при старте? (речь идёт о боковых стенах) [image]

Comment: Забыл указать тип камеры. Они бывают разные и соответственно под разные камеры будут отличатся решения. Например для orthographic камеры решение можно найти здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58941259/how-to-give-the-cameras-edge-collision-in-unity

Comment: на скрине видно что она ортографическая, всё равно спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение для ортографической камеры:

```
// adds EdgeCollider2D colliders to screen edges
// only works with orthographic camera

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace UnityLibrary
{
  public class ScreenEdgeColliders : MonoBehaviour 
  {
    void Awake () 
    {
      AddCollider();
    }

    void AddCollider () 
    {
      if (Camera.main==null) {Debug.LogError("Camera.main not found, failed to create edge colliders"); return;}

      var cam = Camera.main;
      if (!cam.orthographic) {Debug.LogError("Camera.main is not Orthographic, failed to create edge colliders"); return;}

      var bottomLeft = (Vector2)cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, cam.nearClipPlane));
      var topLeft = (Vector2)cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, cam.pixelHeight, cam.nearClipPlane));
      var topRight = (Vector2)cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(cam.pixelWidth, cam.pixelHeight, cam.nearClipPlane));
      var bottomRight = (Vector2)cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(cam.pixelWidth, 0, cam.nearClipPlane));

      // add or use existing EdgeCollider2D
      var edge = GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>()==null?gameObject.AddComponent<EdgeCollider2D>():GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();

      var edgePoints = new [] {bottomLeft,topLeft,topRight,bottomRight, bottomLeft};
      edge.points = edgePoints;
    }
  }
}
```

взято с: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58941259/how-to-give-the-cameras-edge-collision-in-unity

Comment: Ответ мне помог этими строчками
      var bottomLeft = (Vector2)cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, cam.nearClipPlane));
      var topLeft = (Vector2)cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, cam.pixelHeight, cam.nearClipPlane));
      var topRight = (Vector2)cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(cam.pixelWidth, cam.pixelHeight, cam.nearClipPlane));
      var bottomRight = (Vector2)cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(cam.pixelWidth, 0, cam.nearClipPlane));
так как я раньше не знал что есть cam.pixelHeight